# Why don't CompletableFuture methods return CompletionState

Tags: java, completable-future

The return type of any  of the `handle` or `whenComplete` methods on a `CompletableFuture`, is again a `CompletableFuture` instead of a `CompletionStage`.

However, if you would complete the CF on any of those returned instances, the code of the `handle` is not executed.

F.e.:

```
 val handled = AtomicBoolean(false)
 val cf = CompletableFuture<Unit>().whenComplete { _, _ -> handled.set(true) }
 cf.complete(Unit)
 handled.get().shouldBeTrue()
```

In the above code, I would expect the handle to be executed. However it is not. You can complete the original CF and then it works:

```
val handled = AtomicBoolean(false)
val cf = CompletableFuture<Unit>()
cf.whenComplete { _, _ -> handled.set(true) }
cf.complete(Unit)
handled.get().shouldBeTrue()
```

In other words, returning a CF when calling `handle` is pretty confusing b/c you should not complete it but instead, complete the original CF.

So why don't they return a `CompletionStage` instead that would disallow people like me to make such a mistake?

Comment: Because some people *want* a `CompletableFuture` and widening is always possible. There should be no problem when you consider [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The code construction the initial `CompletableFuture` and setting up its completion should not be the code chaining dependent actions. Your mistake can only happen, when you mingle these things within the same method.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but returning a CF from CF methods screams for method chaining, thus, mixing CF initialisation with completion.